# How can I use a pattern that includes regex special characters in Perl's s/// operator?

Tags: regex, perl

The pattern I am using in my `s///` contains regex special characters. How can I quote them so that the regex engine treats them as literal characters.

Can I call a subroutine (`quotemeta`) in the pattern like this?

```
$string =~ s/quotemeta($regex)/$new/g;
```

How can I do it please?

Comment: `$quoted = quotemeta($regex); $string =~ s/$quoted/$new/g;`? As I understand you, the quotemeta should not be part of the search pattern.

Comment: yes but i need to do it in one line , is it possible

Comment: That actually was one line, I think =) But, in addition to the excellent answers below, [this doc on executing perl code inside regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression) may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you want to quote the ***pattern*** in a `s///` operator.

You can do that using the `\Q` and `\E` escapes:

```
$s =~ /\Q[a-z]\E//;
```

would look for the literal string `[a-z]` instead of a single character among `a ... z`.

You can find this, and other useful information in [perldoc perlreref](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlreref#ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) which is installed on your computer alongside `perl`.

Perl comes with excellent documentation. One should periodically skim/read all of it.

Answer (score 3):

few ways:

```
my $quotedregex = quotemeta($regex);
$string =~ s/$quotedregex/$new/g;
```

or

```
$string =~ s/${\quotemeta($regex)}/$new/g;
```

or

```
$string =~ s/\Q$regex\E/$new/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

People may well come here hoping to find a way to insert the return value of a subroutine into a regex pattern *in situ*. Note that this also applies to constants implemented with the [`constant`](https://p3rl.org/constant) pragma, which are implemented as inlined subroutines

There are ways to do that, the traditional ones being to take a reference to the subroutine's return value and dereference the result. This works either as a scalar reference or an anonymous array

There is also the [`Interpolation`](https://p3rl.org/Interpolation) module, which provides tied hashes that look very much like procedure calls and so make your code neater and easier to read

Given this basic program

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Interpolation E => 'eval', mysub => \&mysub;

my $string = '<<<OLD>>>';
my $new    = 'NEW';

sub mysub { 'OLD' }
```

any of the following will replace `OLD` with `NEW` in `$string`

- Dereferencing a reference to the subroutine's return value

  ```
  $string =~ s/${\mysub($regex)}/$new/;
  ```
- Dereferencing an anonymous array containing the subroutine's return value

  ```
  $string =~ s/@{[mysub($regex)]}/$new/;
  ```
- Using `Interpolation`, a simple `eval` (the safe sort)

  ```
  $string =~ s/$E{mysub($regex)}/$new/;
  ```
- Using `Interpolation` with a tied hash `%mysub` to call the subroutine directly

  ```
  $string =~ s/$mysub{$regex}/$new/;
  ```

This demonstrates an answer the original question using `Interpolation` and `quotemeta`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Interpolation Q => \&CORE::quotemeta;

my $string = '<<<+*.$^>>>';
my $regex  = '+*.$^';
my $new    = 'NEW';

$string =~ s/$Q{$regex}/XXX/;

print $string, "\n";
```

#### output

```
<<<XXX>>>
```

***But note*** that the built-in escape `\Q` is clearer and intended for this purpose, so you should use

```
$string =~ s/\Q$regex\E/XXX/
```

in this specific case